# PHP Unit, Testing laravel log messages with unit testing

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, laravel-5, phpunit

I'm using PHPUnit to create a Unit test for a store function that stores data in a database.

Currently, i have a test verifies that it has stored data.

However, I also want to create a test that proves that a laravel log message has been produced if the model save function fails.

The code below shows the store function. The "log::info" is the line I want to test.

Thanks.

```
public function store(Venue $venue){ 
    $saved =  $venue->save();
    if($saved == false){
        Log::info('Failed to Save Venue'. $venue);
    }
 }
```

This what I have so far, i pass an empty model that will cause the save to fail due to database constraints

```
public function test_venue_store_failed(){
   $venue = new Venue();
   $venueRepo = new VenueRepository();
   $this->withExceptionHandling();
   $venueRepo->store($venue);
}
```

Comment: Maybe with something like `if(!$saved){ $saved = 'Failed to Save Venue'. $venue; Log::info($saved);  } return $saved; `

Comment: Below I have answered with 3 ideas  :), Hope one of them will help to solve your problem.

Comment: I do think so . May be you should try with debuging `$saved` instead of `$venue`. or do dumping `$venue` before saving.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can mock the Log facade in your unit test as follows, as per [the docs:](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mocking#mocking-facades)

```
public function test_venue_store_failed(){
    $venue = new Venue();

    Log::shouldReceive('info')
        ->with('Failed to Save Venue'. $venue);

    $venueRepo = new VenueRepository();
    $this->withExceptionHandling();
    $venueRepo->store($venue);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can use event listener on Models.
using this you can get logs on Create or other Events.
Check out the Example Below.
Hope to help .

**Info 1.**

```
<?php
    namespace App;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    use User;
    class Venue extends Model
    {
        protected $fillable = ['title', 'ect..'];
        public static function boot() {
            parent::boot();
            static::created(function($item) {
                \Log::info('venue.created');
            });
            static::updated(function($item) {
                \Log::info('venue.created');
            });
            static::deleted(function($item) {
                \Log::info('venue.created');
            });

        }

    }
```

**Info 2.**

Also there is an exists method on model

```
if ($venue->exists()) {
    // saved 
} else {
    // not saved
}
```

**Info 3**

To get the insert queries when `$venue->save();` error, you can try to catch the exception like this:

```
    try{
       $venue = new Venue;
       $venue->fields = 'example';
       $venue->save(); // returns false
    }
    catch(\Exception $e){
       // do task when error
       \Log::info($e->getMessage());   // insert query
    }
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the ["Log fake" package](https://github.com/timacdonald/log-fake) to make assertions against the log channels, stacks, etc.

Using the package, you could do something like this for the example you shared:

```
LogFake::bind();

$venue = new Venue();
$venueRepo = new VenueRepository();
$venueRepo->store($venue);

Log::assertLogged(fn (LogEntry $log) =>
    $log->level === 'info'
    && $log->message === 'Failed to Save Venue'. $venue
);
```